# How to fix Switch-case with String and Scanner

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

After entering gender (M or F), the programs end immediately without getting to the switch-case

I've tried changing 'string' to "string" and nothing still changed. I thought that would make a difference

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FemurHumerus {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String gender;
    double FemHum;
    double MaleHum;
    double FemFem;
    double MaleFem;
    int FemHumR;
    int MaleHumR;
    int FemFemR;
    int MaleFemR;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is your gender? (M or F): ");
    gender = scan.nextLine();

    switch (gender) {

        case "F":


            System.out.print("Enter femur length: ");
            FemFem = in.nextInt();
            FemFemR = (int) (FemFem*1.94+28.7);

            System.out.print("Enter humerus length: ");
            FemHum = in.nextInt();
            FemHumR = (int) (FemHum*2.8+28.2);


            System.out.println("Height based on femur: "+FemFemR);
            System.out.println("Height based on humerus: "+FemHumR);

            break;

        case "M":

            System.out.print("Enter femur length: ");
            MaleFem = in.nextInt();
            MaleFemR = (int) (MaleFem*1.88+32);

            System.out.print("Enter humerus length: ");
            MaleHum = in.nextInt();
            MaleHumR = (int) (MaleHum*2.9+27.9);


            System.out.println("Height based on femur: "+MaleFemR);
            System.out.println("Height based on humerus: "+MaleHumR);

            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Gender not sprecified.");

            break;
    }

  }

}
```

The expected output should be the height for the specific gender based on femur and humerus

Comment: So your program doesn't print "Gender not sprecified."? Can you attach a debugger to your program and see what happens?

Comment: What is `in`? I don't see a declaration for it.

Comment: I don't think your program should ever compile. What is this `in.nextInt()` thingy?

Comment: Are you entering `f` or `F`? (Or `m` and `M` respectively)

Answer (score 1):

I think due to `in.nextInt();`, that cause in cannot be resolved compile error, 
change all `in.nextInt();` to `scan.nextInt();` then should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I agree; change your `in.nextInt();` to `scan.nextInt()` unless your in is declared and you aren't showing what's its purpose.

[image]

you'll get your switch case then.

Comment: please mark answered for your question btw